# Does "localStorage" in Firefox only work when the page is online?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, html

So I'm toying around with HTML 5 and the localStorage and I'm noticing that my values only get stored when I run the page in Firefox on the local host (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/index.html), but when I run the file locally (file:///C:/test/index.html) my values don't get stored. Safari 4 has no problems with both setups. 
So does anybody know if this is by design -> [DOM Storage on the Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

> (Firefox 2 permitted access to storage
>   objects higher in the domain hierarchy
>   than the current document. This is no
>   longer allowed in Firefox 3, for
>   security reasons. In addition, this
>   proposed addition to HTML 5 has been
>   removed from the HTML 5 specification
>   in favor of localStorage, which is
>   implemented in Firefox 3.5.)

Or if there is a workaround?
I wonder because offline storage that works only online sounds silly :P

If anybody wonders, the code is as easy as it gets:

```
function save()
{
 localStorage.setItem('foo','bar');
}

function load()
{
 var test = localStorage.getItem('foo');
 alert(test);
}
```

Comment: ...but seems working well offline with chrome

Comment: Thank god I found this...I've been trying to debug in Firefox and was wondering where I went wrong because I couldn't see anything wrong with my code. It worked in IE and Chrome while working with file:// URL but Firefox wasn't working. As soon as I put it on a server, it worked just fine.

Comment: Hello, I'm writing to you from the Year 2011. It still ain't fixed! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show%5Fbug.cgi?id=507361

Comment: Hello Futureman!
What a bleak future you are living in!
I hope you wrote this from your flying car!
(For real: What's the holdup? It can't be that of a problem -> see IE, Safari and Chrome)

Comment: +1 for `I wonder because offline storage that works only online sounds silly :P`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems a bug:  [**Bug 507361 -  localStorage doesn't work in file:/// documents**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507361)
Hope is fixed soon!

2011-09-13: Bug fixed, implemented in 'Mozilla8'. I tested this with Firefox 8 and it works now.

Comment: In the meantime you can use Chrome to offline testyour scripts, as it doesn't have this bug.

Comment: Can't check this right now but I think this is the final answer!

Answer (score 21):

Well, the linked document does say that

> localStorage is the same as globalStorage[location.hostname], with the exception of **being scoped to an HTML5 origin** (scheme + hostname + non-standard port)

I don't want to claim that I understand 100% what that means, but the bit in brackets would suggest that the URL needs to have certain properties - in particular that the scheme and hostname are what Firefox considers an HTML 5 origin.  I suspect that `file:///` URLs don't match this, while your `http://127.0.0.1/` does.

*edit*: Looking at the W3C's [description of the Origin property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#origin-0), step 7 looks like it might be causing the problem.  Depending on how the `localStorage` handling is implemented, it may be expecting a 3-tuple as returned by step 12, but for a `file://` URL the return value may be just about anything.

<s>So, er, I suppose it is by design.</s>  On reflection, chances are that this isn't really by design; there's no reason why `localStorage` *shouldn't* work for `file://` URLs.  It might just be a case of the output of one browser-specific implementation not matching the expectations of another.

As for workarounds, would `globalStorage` not do what you want here?

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct 5 2020, localStorage on Firefox seems to be broken again. Try this:

1. Download Mozilla demo page: https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-storage/
2. Change the animal/color to something other than default.
3. close the page's tab (or the browser).
4. Download the page again. It's back to defaults. (Firefox 81:0 et.al.)

Even worse, if you do step 1 & 2 above and then open another copy of the demo in a new tab, not only does the new tab not get the saved data, but the original demo page (refresh it) has gone back to the defaults; as though the new tab STEPPED on the saved data.