# localStorage Getting NULL?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm not sure why, as i've done this before and it worked fine, and i'm thinking it might be because of a browser issue/bug:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')
alert(localStorage.getItem('foo'));
```

I'm in Firefox 3.6.6 and it alerts "bar" but if I do:

```
//localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')
alert(localStorage.getItem('foo'));
```

I get NULL. It should return bar still as it's in my storage.

Also, this is just a web page that it's running on.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question, but basically, it outputs null, but it should still return bar, as it's in my storage no matter if I leave the page, close the browser, or erase my cache/history/etc.

Comment: Where are you running this code from? A filesystem web page, a local server web page, a remote server web page, or from a Firefox add-on?

Comment: @Oscar: Where are you running the web page from? If it's from filesystem (`file://`), Firefox might permanently not store anything in localStorage.

Comment: Thats probably it. Damn it, why would they do that? I guess i dont see the security issue here.

Comment: @Oscar – I think the issue is that different applications running from the local filesystem have access to the same variables, as there are no domains to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you running the script locally via `file:`?

If so, Firefox doesn't appear to allow `localStorage` entries to live beyond unload when `file:` access is used.

For more info, you may want to look at the question: [Is “localStorage” in Firefox only working when the page is online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492942/is-localstorage-in-firefox-only-working-when-the-page-is-online) It's a little dated, but still seems to be applicable.

Comment: Yeah, i think thats it... i was running it locally ill try uploading it, but reading this seems like thats what it is