# Undefined properties in localStorage's 'storage' event

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, dom-events

The event that should be fired when `localStorage` is changed seems to be lacking information in Firefox.

I set up the following event handler:

```
 function storageEventHandler(e){
      alert("key " + e.key);
      alert("oldValue " + e.oldValue);
      alert("newValue " + e.newValue);
      alert("url " + e.url);
 }

 window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);
```

which should be triggered by this:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

However, all the properties in the event (e.g. `e.key` and everything else) are all undefined.  I am using Firefox 3.16.  Why are the event properties undefined?

EDIT.  Here is all the code I am using.  The storage event fires in Firefox 3.16 but not in Firefox 4.0b8

Also, important, I am running it from XAMPP http://localhost/index.html
Running it from file:// make it die [localStorage Getting NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303978/localstorage-getting-null)

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var edit = document.getElementById('edit');

            $(edit).blur(function() {
                localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.innerHTML);
            });

            // when the page loads
            if (localStorage.getItem('todoData')) {
                edit.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todoData');
            }

            window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);

            function storageEventHandler(e){
                alert('localStorage event fired')
            } 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
   <h1> My Simple To-Do List </h1>
 </header>
 <section>
 <ul id="edit" contenteditable="true">
   <li></li>
 </ul>
 </section>
    <em>Add some items, and refresh the page. It'll remember what you typed.</em>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT #2: Here's a simpler example that shows the problem between the browsers...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function storageEventHandler(e){
        alert('localStorage event fired')
    }
    window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
    alert('ok')
</script>

</head>
    <body>
    Test
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox 3.6 (Gecko 1.9.2) doesn't implement these properties (the specification was changing and most other browsers at the time didn't implement these properties either). This is fixed in Firefox 4 (Gecko 2). See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501423

[edit] your testcase is a single-page. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#localStorageEvent) says:

> When the setItem(), removeItem(), and clear() methods are called on a Storage object x that is associated with a local storage area, if the methods did something, then in every HTMLDocument object whose Window object's localStorage attribute's Storage object is associated with the same storage area, **other than x**, a storage event must be fired, as described below.

So you need a separate page on the same domain to observe the event.

Comment: @Alexis K: have a testcase? What version are you testing?

Comment: I added all the code the I am using in the original question.  FYI, if you try and run it, it can't be from file:// it needs to be from a localhost or on a server

Comment: @Alexis K: thanks for the testcase! Edited my answer to explain why the testcase stopped working in Fx4.