# Local storage in javascript that supports both browsers (Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, local-storage

I was not able to retrieve my local storage values in Firefox 4 web browser when i reloaded the same page.

Note: The code below is working fine in the latest Google Chrome web browser

My code:

```
//Set item
var bookmark_value = document.getElementById('bookmark').value;
var storageIndex = "Bookmarked_Page_" + i;              
localStorage[storageIndex] = bookmark_value;

//get item
document.bookmark["bookmark"].value = localStorage["Bookmarked_Page_" + i];
```

Comment: `document.bookmark` is undefined.

Comment: i just getting the local storage item in the text box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [local storage in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660216/local-storage-in-ie). This looks identical. Can you explain why @Darin Dimitrov's answer on that question was not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on the browser adding elements with an ID directly onto the `document`.

```
//get item
document.getElementById('bookmark').value = localStorage["Bookmarked_Page_" + i];
```

Answer (score 0):

typo?

```
document.bookmark["bookmark"].value
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('bookmark').value
```

**Edit**

Oh I think that's your problem, check out this question and answer: [Is "localStorage" in Firefox only working when the page is online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492942/is-localstorage-in-firefox-only-working-when-the-page-is-online/1492990#1492990)

Comment: Ya, you are right .. my query is : local storage values are cleared when i reload the page in firefox4 .. could you please guide me

Comment: FYI: Im executing the sample module in file:/// (URL).

Comment: Hi .. i have fixed the issue now.. I wanted to share this thought to you, i just moved the html file in xampp server .. and i made the ulr to http://localhost/$filename.html.. Thanks