# local storage in IE

Tags: javascript

When I tried to get item from the local storage value , it returns "undefined" in IE8

I'm using the following codes for :

Set item :

```
var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
var key = "i" + x + "test" + y;              
localStorage[key] = value;
```

And get Item:

```
var test   = localStorage["i" + x + "test" + y];
alert(test);
```

It return `undefined`

I followed the same code for firefox 4 and chrome .. it returns the same value which i have set in the local storage

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-support-out-of-the-box-in-localstorage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure you are using the proper HTML5 Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and that you are in IE8 mode (ensure you haven't enabled some compatibility IE7 mode).

Comment: Great.. its working fine now.. i just included <!DOCTYPE html> in the code .. thanks