# Any IE9 Alternative to localStorage that will work with file:// on the Windows 7 phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, persistence, internet-explorer-9, local-storage

Since IE9 cannot be used when running websites in file mode.
Would a (an uggly) solution be to run a local webserver / service on the phone accessing isolatedStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [UserData Persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

It works in IE7/IE8, but I havent tried it in IE9.

Comment: Well, I tried IE9 and it does not work because userData persistence is off by default in the My Computer zone and there is no easy way to configure this. X-UA-Compatible with IE=8 makes it work.