# SDK 2.0p3 seems to have issues with IE9

Tags: rally, agile-central

I just discovered even my simplest 2.0 app fails with IE.  This works fine with 2.0 or 2.0p2, but in IE it fails with SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined sdk-debug.js, line 43756 character 13

This happens on at least one of my other scripts as well.  I'm using IE9.09, and running in debug mode outside of Rally.

```
    Ext.define('FieldEscalations', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'Defect',
            success: function(model) {
                this.grid = this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    model: model,
                    disableColumnMenus: false,

                    columnCfgs: [
                        'FormattedID', 
                        'Tags'
                    ],
                    storeConfig: {
                        filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'State',
                                operator: '<',
                                value: 'Closed'
                            }, {
                                property: 'SupportTicket',
                                operator: '!=',
                                value: ''
                            }
                        ],
                        sorters: [
                            {
                                property: 'CreationDate',
                                direction: 'DESC'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
            scope: this
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails due to the fact that IE9 does not support local storage when running from the file system:

[local storage in IE9 fails when the website is accessed directly from the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706006/local-storage-in-ie9-fails-when-the-website-is-accessed-directly-from-the-file-s)

I will file a defect on this.  Your app should work when running inside a custom html panel on a dashboard in Rally, right?

Comment: Correct-- I don't see this behavior when running in Rally