# Why does localStorage.getItem fail only in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox:

```
var webStorageSupported = ('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null;
if (webStorageSupported && localStorage.getItem("get_list_center") !== null) {
  document.getElementById('mail_listing').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("get_list_center");
}
```

But I get an unknown exception when I view the page in `IE9`. I am able to get both the element and the content in the local storage if I type: `document.getElementById('mail_listing').innerHTML;`
and `localStorage.getItem("get_list_center");` separately in console.

[image: error screen]

When I try to assign the `innerHTML` as the local storage, unknown exception occurs. What Gives???

Edit: As per suggestion from comment, I've tried to get the local storage in a separate variable then assign that variable inside the innerhtml. It turned out that localstorage was indeed retrieving the HTML formatted code, but it wasn't able to save the whole string:

```
<table width="100%">......
   <TD width=\"7%\" align=right>12K &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>\r\n<DIV style=\"DISPLAY: no   
   [[CUT OFF FROM HERE]]
```

I was under the impression that localstorage saves upto 5 MB of text, which is the case for Chrome and Firefox, but maybe this isn't the case for IE9 (Edit: After googling, [IE9 supports up to 10MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) so clearly it's something else). What can I do to solve this problem?

Edit2: I've verified that localStorage is correctly assigning the entire HTML content if it is retrieved right after the content has been set:

```
localStorage.setItem('get_list_center', document.body.innerHTML);
var x = localStorage.getItem('get_list_center'); //GETS THE WHOLE HTML CONTENT CORRECTLY.
```

It's just that when I'm getting the content from somewhere else where I need it from, the content gets cut off. localstorage isn't tampered anywhere else.

Comment: have you tried using an intermediate variable? using console.log in your actual code to verify each step?

Answer (score 1):

If you are browsing from a `file:` URL, this is just one of many reasons we should all switch to Firefox -- [IE9 hates `localStorage` on local documents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706050/1979005).

Comment: No, this is on a test server on IE9, and I'm definitely connecting via http:// URL.