# IE9 throws the error: 'Error: An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions' when running angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, local-storage, console.log

```
I'm getting the error in IE9 when loading my app:
```

Error: An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions
 
Error: Access is denied.

When I debug in IE's dev tools, it points to code regarding localStorage.

```
if (localStorage) {
  // some code
} else {
  // some code
}
```

I'm not sure whether this is an angular-IE issue, or if it's just IE related. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if localStorage is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427636/check-if-localstorage-is-available)

Comment: update: I ended up finding that this is most likely an issue with CORS and IE9. I've looked into using XDomain (https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) but am not too sure on what's being referred to when the mention slave and master domains. ANy ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your app locally? IE9 doesn't support local storage for local files.

There's lots of further explanations from this question:
[local storage in IE9 fails when the website is accessed directly from the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706006/local-storage-in-ie9-fails-when-the-website-is-accessed-directly-from-the-file-s)

Comment: I'm testing on our dev server not locally, but still keep getting the error.

Comment: Are you also looking at the site on your Dev server, or are you looking at it from another machine with http://<yourservername>/whatever.html?

Comment: I'm looking at it form a different machine

Comment: You could try making sure the machine you're using to load your website is running with admin privileges. You can also check IE settings to make sure protected mode isn't enabled (under Internet Options -> Security). IE is flaky with localstorage support, so you might want to test for it specifically in your code:     if(localStorage === "undefined") rather than the way you were originally doing it.

Comment: update: I ended up finding that this is most likely an issue with CORS and IE9. I've looked into using XDomain (github.com/jpillora/xdomain) but am not too sure on what's being referred to when the mention slave and master domains. ANy ideas?

Comment: As you've probably found - there's only partial support for CORS with IE9 (http://caniuse.com/cors). It sounds like you might want to ask a new question around XDomain to get you further.