# using .removeItem in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Using jQuery and localStorage, I want to keep track of how many times a player has won a game. Each time the form is submitted, the wincount or loss count goes up by one depending who won. The counter is working fine, but for some reason, the function to clear the counts is not working. I have been using that same function with `removeItem()` with other variable and it has been working fine.

```
var nicwincount;
var niclosscount;


$('#dostuff').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
         if (playerName === 'nic' && tempresult === win) {
            nicwincount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem (nicwincount));
            nicwincount += 1;
            localStorage.setItem(nicwincount, JSON.stringify(nicwincount));
            console.log(localStorage.getItem(nicwincount));
            console.log(nicwincount);
            }
          else if (playerName === 'nic' && tempresult === loss) {
            losscount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(niclosscount));
            losscount += 1;
            localStorage.setItem (niclosscount, losscount);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem(niclosscount));
            }
}
```

I have tried using `.setItem ()` to set the counts to 0. I have also tried using `.removeItem`. Haven't been able to get either of them to work for me and can't figure out why.

```
$('#clear').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     localStorage.setItem('nicwincount', 0);
            localStorage.setItem('niclosscount', 0);

    }
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

This code works using localStorage

```
var nicScoreList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nicscorelist') || '[]');
    var niccount = 0;
    var nicTotalScore = nicScoreList.reduce(function(total, score) {
        if (score === " " || total === " ") {
            niccount++;
        }
        return +total + +score; 
    });
```

the item i am getting from localStorage is defined on a seperate page as:

```
scorelist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(playerName + 'scorelist') || '[]');
        scorelist.push(" ");
        localStorage.setItem(playerName + 'scorelist', JSON.stringify(scorelist));
        $('div.scorecolumn', column).html("Score: <br>" + scorelist.join('<br>'));
```

I know i skipped a bunch of the code it seems, so let me know if that doesnt make sense.

This code works, but the original example still isn't with nicwincount and niclosscount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using variables to store your items and strings to clear them.

Bareword (i.e. variable) here:

```
localStorage.setItem(nicwincount, JSON.stringify(nicwincount));
```

and string here:

```
localStorage.setItem('nicwincount', 0);
```

Comment: No problem. It's sometimes easy to overlook the obvious things, especially in your own code.

Comment: any idea why when I use console.log(localStorage.getItem('nicwincount')); on another page it just keeps giving me 0? i have a feeling im messing up something string/variable related but not sure

Comment: is the page on the same domain?

Comment: both are in the same folder on my computer. just running files on my computer

Comment: Ah, there are issues with localStorage on localhost, or rather `file://`.  I have run into this before in my own code.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492942/  Although, this is supposedly fixed in firefox.  I would try on a server and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: check updates in the comments above. I have been using this same technique in chrome for a bunch of other stuff and have had no problems