# LocalStorage, stops at browser refresh...Why?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am new to JavaScript, i did this simple code to check local Storage. I just expected this to keep on the storage after refreshing or reopening the file...

Here is my code:

```
function save()
{
   localStorage.setItem('test', 'sometext');
}
```

I call it through a button on HTML. I open it on the Web Inspector and it's there, but once I refresh it's gone. It should stay there right?

Comment: is the file a local file loaded from file system like `file://` or from a web server

Comment: local file through file://

Comment: did you try the code I posted below

Comment: Yeah, It didn't work...Same thing. I refresh the browser, and its cleared. :(

Comment: which is the browser used

Comment: you need to refresh and click on the `get` button to see the alert

Comment: I use Chrome and Safari, both up to date...

Comment: Oh! I see...It worked! Thank's man. So, i gotta always call it back?

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me, I think the problem is when you refresh the Web Inspector is not showing it properly.

Try the following test case

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function save(){
            localStorage.setItem('test', 'sometext');
        }
        function getItem(){
            alert(localStorage.getItem('test'))
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="save()">Save</button>
    <button onclick="getItem()">Get</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you click on `save` then refresh the page and click on `get` to verify.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c6E5s/)

Comment: This is correct. The inspector will not always show the contents of local storage, but the items should still be properly set.

Comment: Hum...i don't understand then. You say it will be stored but i won't see it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should stay there. Unless you are using `file://` URL in Internet Exlporer or older version of Firefox.
There is an in-depth analysis here - [Is “localStorage” in Firefox only working when the page is online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492942/is-localstorage-in-firefox-only-working-when-the-page-is-online) and here - [local storage in IE9 fails when the website is accessed directly from the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706006/local-storage-in-ie9-fails-when-the-website-is-accessed-directly-from-the-file-s).

Comment: Well, file:// its the auto path for the document, no? Its there, but I use Chrome and Safari. I tried the code above, and still. Samething, once I refresh, its gone.